# Factorisation of a quadratic equation

Tags: quadratics, factoring

I've been trying to factorise the following equation in all sorts of ways. The problem I encounter every time is not being able to do anything with the constant i.e. $-20$. Would any of you mind helping me with it?
$$
2x^2 + xy - 6y^2 - 6x + 23y - 20 = 0
$$

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: What is the problem? Just expand
$$2x^2 + xy - 6y^2 - 6x + 23y - 20=(ax+by+c)(dx+ey+f),$$
to get a system of equations that is not at all hard to solve.

Comment: Also it's a general equation of hyperbola...

Answer (score 1):

An obvious start would be
$$(2x-3y)(x+2y)-6x+23y-20.$$
Now try some educated guesses to determine $a$ and $b$ from
$$(2x-3y+a)(x+2y+b)=(2x-3y)(x+2y)-6x+23y-20,$$
making heavy use of $ab=-20$.
You'll end up in $a=4$ and $b=-5$.

Answer (score 1):

The general (Gauß) method consists in writing this equation as an algebraic sum of squares. If it can be factored, you obtain a difference of squares.

First group all terms with an $x$, and complete the square:
\begin{align}
&\phantom{{}={}}(2x^2 + xy - 6x)- 6y^2  + 23y - 20=2\bigl(x^2 +\tfrac12xy -3x\bigr)- 6y^2  + 23y - 20 \\
&=\Bigl[2\bigl(x +\tfrac14y -\tfrac32\bigr)^2-\tfrac18y^2+\tfrac32y-\tfrac92\Bigr]- 6y^2  + 23y - 20 \\
&=2\bigl(x +\tfrac14y -\tfrac32\bigr)^2-\tfrac{49}8y^2+\tfrac{49}2y-\tfrac{49}2=\tfrac18\Bigl[16\bigl(x +\tfrac14y -\tfrac32\bigr)^2-49\bigl(y^2-4y+4\bigr)\Bigr] \\
&=\tfrac18\Bigl[(4x+y-6)^2-\bigl(7(y-2)\bigr)^2\Bigr].
\end{align}
Can you end the computation?

Answer (score 1):

Note that, asymptotically, $2x^2 + xy - 6y^2=(2x-3y)(x+2y)$. Therefore, the factorized equation takes the form,

$$
2x^2 + xy - 6y^2 - 6x + 23y - 20 = (2x-3y+k_1)(x+2y+k_2)
$$

Then, setting $x=0$ in above equation,

$$6y^2-23y+20=(3y-k_1)(2y+k_2)$$

which yields $k_1=4$ and $k_2=-5$. Thus,

$$
2x^2 + xy - 6y^2 - 6x + 23y - 20 = (2x-3y+4)(x+2y-5)
$$